# how to set marker at my current location and change camera position in Baidu Map (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, marker, baidu-map

I configure Baidu map in my code using `pod 'BaiduMapKit`' and display map in view.
how to set a marker at my current location in Baidu Map and change camera position also?

// now I solve how to set marker but actually my camera location not move.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
           [super viewDidLoad];
           anotation = [[BMKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
           CLLocationCoordinate2D coor;

           coor.latitude  = 22.2593;
           coor.longitude  = 70.7777;
           anotation.coordinate = coor;
           anotation.title  = @"this is rajkot";
           [mapView addAnnotation:anotation];
           mapView.delegate = self;

     }
```

Comment: `[yourMapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];`?

Comment: Please put your tried code

Comment: @arunjos007 now i put my code but now i solve one issue how to set marker but now my question is how to set camera position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coor;
coor.latitude  = 22.2593;
coor.longitude  = 70.7777;
mapView.centerCoordinate = coor
```

try this to change the camera

Comment: if you have any idea about "How to Implement Map Places autocomplete in Baidu Map for IOS SDK" so please give me a answer in my Question  check my profile and go to the Question

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       anotation = [[BMKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
       CLLocationCoordinate2D coor;
       coor.latitude  = 22.2593;
       coor.longitude  = 70.7777;
       anotation.coordinate = coor;
       anotation.title  = @"this is rajkot";
       [mapView addAnnotation:anotation];
       mapView.centerCoordinate = coor;
       mapView.delegate = self;
 }
```